# Compile error with boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, trim

I'm beginner using boost library.

```
#include<boost/version.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "My first boost program with version:" <<BOOST_LIB_VERSION<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

The above code returns with no compilation or execution errors.

output:
    `My first boost program with version:1_33_1`

But I'm facing compile error when I include boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp in my .cpp file.

```
#include<boost/version.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>    
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "My first boost program with version:" <<BOOST_LIB_VERSION<< endl;
return 0;
}

at this point in file   device_tml      line 35, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
at this point in file   device_tml      line 41, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
expected ';' before 'str_end'   device_tml      line 57, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before ',' token    device_tml      line 57, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before ';' token    device_tml      line 111, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp    C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before ')' token    device_tml      line 57, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before '*' token    device_tml      line 57, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
no matching function for call to 'str_end()'    device_tml      line 103, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/end.hpp   C/C++ Problem
no matching function for call to 'str_end()'    device_tml      line 108, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/end.hpp   C/C++ Problem
no matching function for call to 'str_end()'    device_tml      line 111, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp    C/C++ Problem
no matching function for call to 'str_end()'    device_tml      line 113, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/end.hpp   C/C++ Problem
no matching function for call to 'str_end()'    device_tml      line 98, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/end.hpp    C/C++ Problem
return-statement with no value, in function returning 'char*'   device_tml      line 103, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/begin.hpp C/C++ Problem
    return-statement with no value, in function returning 'const char*' device_tml      line 98, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/begin.hpp  C/C++ Problem
return-statement with no value, in function returning 'const wchar_t*'  device_tml      line 108, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/begin.hpp C/C++ Problem
return-statement with no value, in function returning 'wchar_t*'    device_tml      line 113, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/begin.hpp C/C++ Problem
too few arguments to function 'size_t strlen(const char*)'  device_tml      line 243, external location: /usr/include/string.h  C/C++ Problem
too few arguments to function 'size_t wcslen(const wchar_t*)'   device_tml      line 243, external location: /usr/include/wchar.h   C/C++ Problem
const wchar_t* boost::range_detail::str_end(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*) device_tml      line 39, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
```

Compiler Version

```
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
```

Compiler options

```
-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fpic -o
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting issue, but could you please insert the text of the error messages rather than a screenshot so we can see the full description. Please also tell us the compiler version and compiler flags, as that might also be useful.

Comment: If I'm reading the documentation right boost 1.33 is 11 years old: It may just have incompatibilities with modern compilers. Have you tried a more recent version of boost?

Comment: I just tried this with the current boost (1.61 development version), and it compiled w/o errors.

Comment: I have not tried with the new version of boost as I do not have permission to install in my work computer.

Comment: @MarkB gcc 4.1.2 which he uses is more or less as old as boost 1.33

Comment: The flag "-o" makes no sense. It should be "-o <file>", if anything.

Comment: Try adding `#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>`

Comment: @Wurmloch Thanks for your suggestion. But still its the same, lots of compilation errors. 


    "expected primary-expression before ',' token device_tml  line 57, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before ';' token device_tml  line 111, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before ')' token device_tml  line 57, external location: /usr/include/boost/range/detail/implementation_help.hpp C/C++ Problem" 
etc

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by placing the header

```
#include <boost/algorithm/str‌​ing.hpp>
```

on top at first line. I'm not sure of the reason why it worked.

Thanks